# Android chat box type thing

Tags: java, android

Question, what kind of thing would i use for this?

[image]
<sub>(source: [nationmultimedia.com](http://www.nationmultimedia.com/new/2012/02/03/national/images/30175084-01_big.jpg))</sub>

Basically where when i type in my reply in the right, and the apps reply is on the left

Comment: Rudy, remove the space between www.

Comment: Worked for the guy who answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a ton of ways to do this.

The easiest is to use a table layout, and have each row contain a Drawable for the avatar and a nine-patch for the chat bubble.

Whenever someone adds to the conversation, add a row to the table.  Depending on which person said it, draw starting from either the left or the right.

Also, ya might want to wrap the table in a `ScrollView`.

By the way, this is a working solution, not the best one.  You could use a `ListView`, but that's slightly more complicated.

More information about 9-patch images can be found here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html

Comment: Hi, what is a nine patch? and where can i find it?